# android upload an image via http

Tags: java, android, file-upload, connection

I'm trying to upload an image file (jpeg) to my test server using the method posted here a while ago:

```
                  try {
         String pathToOurFile = path;
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = 
         new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream,3000);
         byte[] bt=new byte[bis.available()];

        HttpURLConnection connection = 
        (HttpURLConnection)new  URL(string).openConnection();
         connection.setDoOutput(true);
         connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         connection.connect();

        FileOutputStream input =  (FileOutputStream) connection.getOutputStream();
        input.write(bt);
        bis.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Context context = null;

        Toast.makeText(context, "error in writing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

I'm getting an ClassCastException at this line: FileOutputStream input =  (FileOutputStream) connection.getOutputStream(); thought Eclipse doesnt mark it as an error. How can I fix that?

P.S. the project is compiled against API lvl 17

Answer (score 1):

The stream returned by `getOutputStream()` is not a `FileOutputStream`, so your cast is failing. Eclipse is not warning because by doing the cast, you are telling it that you know that the result will be a `FileOutputStream`.

Just change the variable type to `OutputStream` and remove the cast.

Comment: I tried so, but nothing seems to happen. The file is not on the server and there are no information in the LogCat window.. Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to upload the image?

Answer (score 0):

Just change FileOutputStream to OutputStream